# How can I get rid of Abs?

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, physics, assumptions, eigenvalues

In the following code, the functions WP[t] and WS[t] are real. Time also is a positive parameter. As you can see, MATHEMATICA enters Abs in the calculations. Including Abs only complicates the next parameters and  calculations that cause the program to not run. In order not to complicate the calculations, how should I correct the code so that MATHEMATICA does not include Abs in the calculations??

```
m = {{0, WP[t], 0}, {WP[t], 0, WS[t]}, {0, WS[t], 0}};
q = Eigenvectors[m];
p1 = Normalize[q[[1]]]
p2 = Normalize[q[[2]]]
p3 = Normalize[q[[3]]]


{-(WS[t]/(Sqrt[1 + Abs[WS[t]/WP[t]]^2] WP[t])), 0, 1/Sqrt[
 1 + Abs[WS[t]/WP[t]]^2]}

{WP[t]/(Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*WS[t]), 
-(Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/(Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + 
   Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*WS[t])), 
  1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]}


 {WP[t]/(Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*WS[t]), 
   Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/
   (Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*WS[t]), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]}
```

Comment: If you know that `WP[t],WS[t]` are real and positive try `p1=Simplify[Normalize[q[[1]] ], {WS[t] > 0, WP[t] > 0}]`

Comment: If you know they're all positive and _all_ usages of `Abs` in these expressions are redundant, you could replace using for example: `Normalize[q[[1]]]/.Abs->Identity`, but using `Simplify` is safer.

Comment: Don't exercise and drink a six-pack of beer daily!

Answer (score 3):

Add `/. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify` at the end of every line.

```
m = {{0, WP[t], 0}, {WP[t], 0, WS[t]}, {0, WS[t], 0}};
q = Eigenvectors[m];
p1 = Normalize[q[[1]]] /. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify
p2 = Normalize[q[[2]]] /. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify
p3 = Normalize[q[[3]]] /. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify

{-(WS[t]/(Sqrt[1 + Abs[WS[t]/WP[t]]^2] WP[t])), 0, 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[WS[t]/WP[t]]^2]} /. Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify

{WP[t]/(Sqrt[
       1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*
      WS[t]), -(Sqrt[
       WP[t]^2 + 
        WS[t]^2]/(Sqrt[
         1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + 
          Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*WS[t])), 
   1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + 
      Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]} /. 
  Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify


{WP[t]/(Sqrt[
       1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*
      WS[t]), Sqrt[
     WP[t]^2 + 
      WS[t]^2]/(Sqrt[
       1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]*
      WS[t]), 1/
    Sqrt[1 + Abs[WP[t]/WS[t]]^2 + 
      Abs[Sqrt[WP[t]^2 + WS[t]^2]/WS[t]]^2]} /. 
  Abs -> RealAbs // Simplify
```

Comment: `ComplexExpand` will assume that all values are real.

Comment: @BobHanlon Yes, 'ComplexExpand' is powerful environment to simplify expression.